# How to filter multiple documents with SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

In my Web App I have a SQL query which I run:

```
string query = "SELECT Id, filename, datestamp FROM FileTable WHERE filename = 'Document - Test (Test).pdf'";
```

Which works great, but I have several files with the same name apart from the last bit.

```
 Document - Test (Test1).pdf
 Document - Test (Test2).pdf
```

How can alter the query to look for every file containing `Document - Test *.pdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Like` and use `%` instead of *

```sql
SELECT Id, filename, datestamp FROM FileTable WHERE filename like 'Document - Test%.pdf'
```

Also check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp for more information about the wildcards and `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `LIKE` operator with `%` operator.  Where:

- `LIKE` operator allow to determine whether a specific character string matches a specified pattern
- The percent wildcard `%` allows any or no characters star

So query should look look this:

```
string query = "SELECT Id, filename, datestamp FROM FileTable 
    WHERE filename LIKE 'Document - Test%'";
```

The percent wildcard % allows any or no character